# Problema con foreign key al borrar artista en java

Tags: java, sql

Buenas, estoy haciendo un programa para añadir/eliminar/modificar artistas de una base de datos y cuando intento borrar el artista me salta esto:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`chinook`.`album`, CONSTRAINT `FK_AlbumArtistId` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`ArtistId`) REFERENCES `artist` (`ArtistId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:932)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
>     at modelo.dao.ArtistaDAO.eliminarArtista(ArtistaDAO.java:103)   at
>   vista.VistaArtistasBuscar.actionPerformed(VistaArtistasBuscar.java:164)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Creo que se cual es el problema, y que debería hacer `on delete cascade`, pero no se como hacerlo para que el programa lo ejecute una sola vez, ya que no puedo hacer cambios en la propia base de datos, todo debe ser a traves del programa.

Comment: Borra los registros hijos, luego el padre. Si quieres, en sentencias separadas dentro de una misma transacción.

Comment: Consulta un artista puede tener 1 o muchos album?

Answer (score 3):

No es necesario activar el `on delete cascade`, la excepción `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` indica que se está cometiendo una violación de la integridad de los datos, antes de eliminar un `Artist` tienes que eliminar todas las tuplas de la tabla `AlbumArtist` que tengan una referencia a esa tupla de Artist.

Puedes hacerlo con sentencias independientes dentro de la transacción como:

```
for(AlbumArtist someAlbumArtist :someArtist.getAlbums()){
   AlbumDAO.delete(someAlbumArtist);
}

ArtistDAO.delete(someArtist);
```

Donde `someAlbum` y `someArtist` están relacionados (se tienen que eliminar todo los álbumes)

O en su defecto puede activar el `on delete cascade` como intuiste pues nunca existirá un album sin artista y es lógico eliminarlos junto con él.

No te olvides de hacer `commit();` al final de todo.

Comment: Voy a probar como me has dicho, también me gustaría saber como activar `on delete cascade` pero que solo se aplique una vez y no se repita mas, ya que me gustaría pues tener mas opciones a la hora de solucionar un error como este.

Comment: `on delete cascade` se define en la estructura y no puede variar. Incluso en ORMs como Hibernate es una cuestión de estructura invariable en tiempo de ejecución. Hay soluciones utilizando procedimientos almacenados como [este](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116968/in-sql-server-2005-can-i-do-a-cascade-delete-without-setting-the-property-on-my).

Answer (score 0):

Esto es debido a que hay registros existentes relacionado a la frk que se ha borrado entonces genera un conflicto ya que esta buscando un dato que ya no existe en la base de datos, antes de borrar una frk se recomienda borrar todas las tuplas correspondientes a ella y después eliminar la frk

Answer (score 0):

No puedes borrar los registros de la tabla Artista ya que la clave foránea depende de otros registros de otra tabla, primero elimina los registros de otras tablas que contenga la llave foránea de Artista, primero tu programa haz que elimine la tabla album_artista

```
 delete from album_artista ab inner join artista ar on ab.artista_id = ar.artista_id  where ab.artista_id = ?
```